# ¿Como lograr que los comentarios en visual studio aparezcan en Italica?

Tags: visual-studio, atajo

Genero esta pregunta ya que no estoy pudiendo realizar comentarios en italica en Visual Studio code, les adjunto imagen de como quisiera que se vea

[![Asi quisiera que se vea el texto de mis comentarios en Italica][1]][1]

Abro el archivo json y copio y pego lo que me dijeron pero me arroja error

```
    {
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false
        
}

{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": [
              //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
              "comment",
              "entity.name.type.class", //class names
              "keyword", //import, export, return…
              "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
              "storage.modifier", //static keyword
              "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
            ],
            "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
          },
          {
            "scope": [
              //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
              "invalid",
              "keyword.operator",
              "constant.numeric.css",
              "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
              "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
              "constant.numeric.json"
            ],
            "settings": {
              "fontStyle": ""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4UQ.png
```

Answer (score 0):

## Agregue esto a settings.json ( ctrl + ,o cmd + ,)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
        "comment",
        "entity.name.type.class", //class names
        "keyword", //import, export, return…
        "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
        "storage.modifier", //static keyword
        "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
        "invalid",
        "keyword.operator",
        "constant.numeric.css",
        "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
        "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
        "constant.numeric.json"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hola Hernan, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Recien estoy arrancando y no se donde debo agregar lo que me indicas...

Comment: Encontre lo que me decias, pero me tira error...

Comment: Solo remplaza los códigos comparalos y mira cuál es la diferencia.

Comment: Perfecto, eso intentare. Sabes en que parte debo agregar el codigo para verlo asi /* === Results === */ cuando quiero que mis comentarios me aparezcan con los simbolos de iguales. Pude encontrar para comentar de manera rapida pero no se donde debo ir para agregar que mis comentarios salgan asi con los simbolos iguales. Si me podes ayudar te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Lo logre!!! pude poner el atajo para el comentario, lo que no pude hacer todavia es que me aparezca de esta manera el lugar para el comentario          /* === Footer === */ 

Asi con los iguales